# Design Pattern for converting objects to/from bytes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class A that contains instances of several other Classes B, C and D [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YzpX.png).

I want to convert Class A and its contents to an array of bytes and store them in a file. Later I want to read the byte array from the file and convert it back to an instance of Class A [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhHXO.png). I'm having trouble designing an elegant solution that converts back and forth between objects and byte arrays.

One solution I considered was creating a single converter class that can convert back and forth between all my objects and byte arrays :

```
public Converter{

   public static ClassA getInstance(byte[] b){...return new ClassA()}
   public byte[] getBytes(ClassA classA){...}

   public static ClassB getInstance(byte[] b){...return new ClassB()}
   public byte[] getBytes(ClassB classB){...}

}
```

This approach results in a very large class with a lot of methods.

Another approach is to make a "Converter class" for each class that I want to store in the file.

```
public ClassAConverter extends Converter<ClassA>{

   public ClassA getInstance(byte[] b){...return new ClassA()}
   public static byte[] getBytes(ClassA classA){...}

}

public ClassBConverter extends Converter<ClassB>{

   public ClassB getInstance(byte[] b){...return new ClassB()}
   public static byte[] getBytes(ClassB classB){...}

}
```

This design however seems to have the disadvantage of creating a large amount of classes.

I'm that aware that Java Serialization achieves most of what I've described here, but I'm looking for a more flexible and customized solution that also enables the file to be parsed by other independant programs. Furthermore file size is a concern and using a custom binary format allows for good space efficiency.

Is there any design pattern that could help implement the conversion logic more elegantly?

Comment: This is the [Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), Java implements it through serialization. It is very flexible, I would strongly recommend against inventing a better mousetrap for this purpose.

Comment: Have you considered using XML (JAXB), JSON (GSON/Jackson) or Protobuf?

Comment: @larsgrefer I should have mentioned that file size is a concern and it is my understanding that formats such as XML and JSON has low space effiency. I have updated the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't re-invent the wheel here, there are many existing formats for serialized objects and even more libraries for converting them from and to java objects.

The most common formats are XML or JSON. For writing and reading these formats in java you could use JAXB, Jackson or GSON. Since size effiency is important for you, you could compress the generated XML/JSON before storing it to the filesystem (java as GZipInputStream and GZipOutputStream for this. Alternatively you could use Okio's GZipSink/GZipSource).

If you really want to use a custom binary format, I recommend to use protobuf: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Here you describe your data-format in a special `.proto` file and protobuf will generate the java classes and all parsing code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a java programmer, but unless size really matter I would use a json serializer. I am sure you have a lib which allow you to customize it as you like and can be used by any other program.

Comment: I should have mentioned that file size is in fact a concern and that it is part of the reason I am manually converting to/from bytes. I have updated the post to reflect this.